# Content of $_SESSION different in another page - PHP

Tags: php, session, urlencode, encode

I have two files:

"save.php" - Get the contents of a form and puts in a session.
"save_db.php" - Saves the contents of the session in the database.

But the content is not getting the right "save_db.php", see:

"save.php":

```
<?php
session_start();

$str = "ãÃóÓôÔ*&Q^#&*%&^!^%!(//\\\\>";
$_SESSION["msg"] = $str;

echo $_SESSION["msg"];
// return ãÃóÓôÔ*&Q^#&*%&^!^%!(//\\\\>
?>
```

"save_db.php":

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION["msg"];

//return Ã£ÃƒÃ³Ã“Ã´Ã”*&Q^#&*%&^!^%!(//\\\\>
?>
```

In save.php, the return is: **ãÃóÓôÔ*&Q^#&*%&^!^%!(//\\>**
In save_db.php, the return is: ***Ã£ÃƒÃ³Ã“Ã´Ã”*&Q^#&*%&^!^%!(//\\>***
The correct return is '**ãÃóÓôÔ*&Q^#&*%&^!^%!(//\\>**'.
How To Fix? Can anyone help me?

Comment: This because encoding in these files are different, try to add UTF-8 header to both files and check again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encoding is different in either file.  To fix this, explicitly state encoding or type in characters that aren't so weird. ;)

Answer (score -1):

I know PHP htmlspecialchars() Function is used to deal with HTML characters in your PHP variable but, would you try using this in your case?

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlspecialchars.asp